# React Navigation v6 - Nested Tab Stack navigation and back

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I have a navigation structure set up as below:

- Tab 1

  - Screen 1 (Initial Page)
  - Screen 2
- Tab 2

  - Screen 3 (Initial Page)
  - Screen 4

Scenario:
There will be cases when Screen 1 has to directly navigate to Screen 4. What I wanted to do is to go back from Screen 4 back to Screen 1, and when I navigate back to Tab 2 by clicking on the tab buttons, it should show me Screen 3.

Steps:

1. Triggered a navigation from Screen 1 to 4, works totally fine:

   ```js
   this.props.navigation.navigate("Tab 2", {
     screen: "Screen 4",
     initial: false,
     params: {...some params}
   })
   ```
2. Triggered a goBack function on Screen 4, which redirects back to Screen 3, which is fine:

   ```js
   goBack() {
     this.props.navigation.goBack();
   }
   ```
3. Click on Tab 1 and redirect back to Screen 1. Works fine.
4. Problem occurs: Click on Tab 2, but showing Screen 4, which I want it to be showing Screen 3.

I looked up on other posts saying that one way is to reset the stack actions or something like that but I couldn't a hang of it.

Versions:

```json
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.3",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
```

**Update**

Found this reference on the internet and got it working. (https://www.reactnativeschool.com/reset-stack-inside-tab-after-leaving-tab)

*v6 seems does not support dangerouslyGetState() function, and replaced with getState() instead.*

1. Create a function like below

```js
  TabPressListener = ({ navigation, route }: any) => ({
    tabPress: (e: any) => {
      const state = navigation.getState();
      if (state) {
        // Grab all the tabs that are NOT the one we just pressed
        const nonTargetTabs = state.routes.filter((r: any) => r.key !== e.target);

        nonTargetTabs.forEach((tab: any) => {
          // Grab the key of the nested stack
          const stackKey = tab?.state?.key;

          // Pass the stack key that we want to reset and use popToTop to reset it
          navigation.dispatch({
            ...StackActions.popToTop(),
            target: stackKey,
          });
        });
      }
    }
  })
```

2. On the Tab.Screen component, add property "listener" which reference the above function.

```
<Tab.Screen
   name={'Tab 1'}
   listener={this.TabPressListener}
>
{...}
</Tab.Screen>

<Tab.Screen
   name={'Tab 2'}
   listener={this.TabPressListener}
>
{...}
</Tab.Screen>
```

*Previously I had the flag "unmountOnBlur" set to TRUE. And ever since I commented this line of setting (which then defaults to FALSE) together with triggering the function on Step 1, the stack under each tab is reseting whenever exiting.*

*Hope this helps for those who got stuck on the same issue.*

Answer (score 0):

To reset the navigation options navigate to Tab 2 with this code:

```
navigation.reset({index:0, routes: [{name: “Tab 2”}]})
```

Comment: Do you mean adding a tab press listener inside the Tab.Screen component, and trigger the above reset function?

Comment: You want it to reset to the default screen of the Tab 2 navigator every time you click on Tab 2 so call this function when the Tab 2 button is pressed. Using a listen one way to do that.

Comment: After drilling down on this direction, got it working as documented on above. Thanks for the help!